# How to format the request body for Google Sheets API batchUpdate method?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am using Apps Script to connect to and manipulate a Google Sheet. Using the single update method works fine:

```
function updateOneCell() {
    var spreadsheetId = spreadsheetID;
    var request = {
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
        values: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    };
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(
      request,
      spreadsheetId,
      "'Occupancy Report'!C5:L5",
      {valueInputOption: "RAW"}
    );
}
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong with the format of my request body when trying to use batchUpdate:

```
function outputOccupancyReport() {
    var params = {
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetID,
    };

    var batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {
      valueInputOption: "RAW",  
      data: [[{"range": "'Occupancy Report'!C5:L5", "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}]],  
    };

    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody);
}
```

`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Requested entity was not found.`

I'm sure there is an issue with the way I'm formatting my data field. This is the documentation I'm trying to follow: [spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Can anyone help shed some light on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function outputOccupancyReport() {
  var spreadsheetID = "XXX";
  var batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {
    valueInputOption: "RAW",
    data: [{
      "range": "'Occupancy Report'!C5:L5",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    }],      
  };

  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(batchUpdateValuesRequestBody, spreadsheetID);
}
```

I used [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#write_values_to_multiple_ranges) for reference and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked perfectly straight away. I wish that very clear example was on the main doc page for this function and not buried under "Advanced"!